# Find a value of $\ln 1.2$ with accuracy of $10^{-4}$

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion, approximation

I know the formula that helps find an approximate value. In this instance it would be like $\ln 1.2 = \ln (1 + 0.2) \approx 0 + 1 \cdot 0.2 = 0.2$.

But I need to find the value more precisely. I calculated, that the value is $0.18232155679$ so I need an accuracy that can determine it to be $0.1823$. How to I do that?

Comment: If you tagged it as `taylor-expansion`, then surely you know what to try?

Comment: You need to clarify the context of your question. What tools are you allowed to use?

Answer (score 1):

The taylor series for $ln(1+x)$ is an alternating series. So the error is less than the last term dropped. So you have to continue your expansion until you reach a term that has a value smaller than $10^{-4}$. So, you are actually solving $\frac{0.2^{n}} {n}$ such that it is smaller than the error you want.